# ARMv7 stm32-L476G How to set a specific pitch of sound to play for a specific duration

Tags: arm

I am new to ARMv7 assembly programming (using the stm32-L476G) and I am lost on how to produce a specific-pitched sound (e.g 110 hz) to play for 15 seconds. I have done my research and reached a dead end. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You mean a sine wave from an ADC? What sample rate? What did your research show so far?

Comment: Give up assembly programming of those uCs. It is pointless and your assembler usually will by worse than the compiler generated code. Good luck in writing TCP or USB stack im assembler

Answer (score 0):

## method A

1. Configure the timer to generate 110Hz PWM 50% signal.
2. Configure another timer to overflow after 15 seconds.
3. In the second timer interrupt deactivate the PWM signal generation by the first timer

## method B

1 configure the timer to overflow every 1/220 sec.

2. In the timer interrupt toggle the pin
3. count the number the interrupts when the number reaches the 220*15 disable timer

## method C

1 create the sine tabue table in the memory.

2. confiure the timer to trigger DMA transfer to DAC every
   1/(110*nsamples_per_period)
3. configure DMA in the circular mode
4. in the DMA end transfer interrupt increase the counter
5. when the counter is >= 110*15 disable the triggering timer